# Open IE with multiple tabs

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

I'm trying to create an AutoHotkey script that can be added to the Startup folder, to open IE with multiple predetermined tabs. I have several websites at work that I use regularly, & I want to have IE automatically open when I first login with these pages loaded. I've searched & found a few AHKs which I've tried to alter for my needs, but I receive errors with them. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
Pwb :=  COM_CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")
Pwb.Visible:=True
Pwb.Navigate("https://*****.org/***/") 
Pwb.Navigate2("https://*****", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate3("http://*****", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate4("http://*****", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate5("*****", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate6("*****", 2048)
Return
```

When I launch this I receive error "The following variable name contains an illegal character: "Pwb.Visible"  The program will exit."
If I try to just delete that part of the code, I then get errors on my websites: "Error: Call to nonexistent function.  Specifically: Pwb.Navigate("https://.org/**/")  The program will exit."

Comment: @Teemu The `.` syntax is available in recent AutoHotkey versions to access object members.

Comment: @NbdNnm OK, comment removed, it would be irrelevant now =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Make sure you have the latest version of AutoHotkey (v1.1+). `COM_CreateObject()` should be `ComObjCreate()` and there are no Navigate3, Navigate4, or Navigate5... methods available in that object.

```
Pwb :=  ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
Pwb.Visible:=True
Pwb.Navigate("http://www.google.com") 
Pwb.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate("http://news.google.com", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate("https://www.quora.com/", 2048)
Return
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I think it was because I didn't update to the latest version of Autohotkey. I had tried a similar version of code before switching to the one I posted, but I was having the same error then. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: so now, to make my request even more difficult, I have a box that pops up for one of those webpages that requests username & password. I would like to find a way to have it autofill my username & password! Then, if possible, I would also like to have a 2nd window auto-open (after a waiting period that allows that first window to login). Any takers??

Comment: @user1853767 I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: I did: Fill in username & password, then open another IE window