# Fill in username & password, then open another IE window

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open IE with multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567780/open-ie-with-multiple-tabs)

I was trying to create an AutoHotkey script that can be added to the Startup folder, to open IE with multiple predetermined tabs. I have several websites at work that I use regularly, & I wanted to have IE automatically open when I first logged in with these pages loaded. Here is the code I was given (& it works great):

```
Pwb :=  ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
Pwb.Visible:=True
Pwb.Navigate("http://www.google.com") 
Pwb.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate("http://news.google.com", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate("https://www.quora.com/", 2048)
Return
```

So now, to make my request even more difficult, I have a separate box that pops up for one of those webpages that requests username & password. I would like to find a way to have it autofill my username & password! Then, if possible, I would also like to have a 2nd window auto-open with its own tabs (after a waiting period that allows that first window to login). Any takers?

Comment: The sites in the example code do not have pop up windows for users to login. So they are not the ones you really want. Methods for automating web page logins vary depending on the web site. You should at least provide the information which site you are talking about.

Comment: No, actually this was the example code you gave me that helped me fix my original problem. As these are work websites, I'm not certain how much information I should post. Basically it is the site that houses all information on the Active Directory accounts for users & devices within my work's domain. The window that loads is a separate popup window that stays in the forefront, even if other tabs are launched at the same time. Once it launches, the blinking cursor automatically shows up in the username box.

Comment: I can usually use a code like this to fill the information once the box appears (but I don't know how to incorporate it into the above code so that it's automated, & then launch a new window once it's finished logging in):
    ::actd@::
    Send username{Tab}
    Sleep, 500
    Send password
    Sleep, 500
    Send {Enter}
    return