# Launching IE with multiple tabs using autohotkey

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

I previously posted a question regarding this (see [Open IE with multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567780/open-ie-with-multiple-tabs) ), back when my work was using Windows XP & IE8. I was able to get it working thanks to the Answer listed, & had no further issues. Now I've upgraded to Windows 7 at work (still using IE8), & this script is no longer working. I had to redownload ahk, so I'm using the newest version. When I try to launch this .ahk, I receive the error "Error at line 18.  The following variable name contains an illegal character: "Pwb.Visible"  The program will exit." I tried removing this part, but then I receive "Error: call to nonexistent function.  Specifically: ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application") ..... The program will exit." I'm not sure what has changed between Windows XP & Windows 7 that makes this .ahk no longer function correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

SCRIPT:

```
{
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application") 
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("https...")
wb.Navigate("http...", 2048) 
wb.Navigate("http...", 2048)
wb.Navigate("http.../", 2048)
wb.Navigate("http...", 2048)
wb.Navigate("https...", 2048) 
WinMaximize, A
Sleep, 5000
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("http...")
wb.Navigate("P:\Stuff\FrameHome.html", 2048)
wb.Navigate("http...", 2048)
WinMaximize, A 
Sleep, 5000
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("http...")
WinMaximize, A 
Sleep, 5000
Run C:\Program Files\....exe
Sleep, 20000
Run C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Sleep, 30000 
Run C:\Program Files\KatMouse\KatMouse.exe 
Run P:\....xlsx
Return
}
```

Comment: Did you download it from [ahkscript.org](http://ahkscript.org/download/)? Also, please post your script.

Comment: Please use the  `edit` link in order to include the code in your question, then delete the comments.

Answer (score 1):

[MCL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1282023/mcl) called it, you need the version from http://ahkscript.org as the current download at autohotkey,com is an over 5 year old version sorry :(

That's all there is to it, just get the newest version and it will work again...

Hope it helps

Comment: I'll try that! I actually misunderstood MCL's question. I thought he was asking if I got the script from ahkscript, not the version of autohotkey. I didn't realize that the version at the "official" site was so outdated. When I get back into work on Mon, I'll test out the newer version & let you know if that fixed it!

Comment: Well that partially fixed the problem. Almost everything now launches correctly, but some things are still not working. I'm supposed to have 3 separate IE windows open, but only the first one is opening. Also, I have an Excel file that I want to launch (down near the bottom), & Excel opens but the file itself is not opening. My previous PC (where this script used to work) had Excel 2007, & the new one has Excel 2010, so I'm not sure if that's the problem with Excel. But I don't understnad why IE won't open multiple windows like I asked it to.

Comment: The weird thing is, I have another .ahk file with just those IE window scripts (in case IE gets buggy & I have to close it & just want to run the IE launch part), & that .ahk launches all 3 IE windows without issue. So I'm not sure why I can launch them with that, but I can't launch the 3 windows with this script, which is identical in that portion.

Comment: So I've discovered a new delimma. My work uses Java in IE for various functions, & it seems like the IE windows that I open using these scripts don't register that Java is installed. However, if I just open a fresh IE window using IE's shortcut, it works fine. Any idea why windows created using the "Pwb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")" function wouldn't recognize Java? Is it possible for me to just us a "Run C....Iexplore.exe" script & still get it to open all the tabs I need? Still having trouble with Excel opening my file too....

Comment: So I don't know if anyone is still following this, but I found a new way to do it on the autohotkey forums, but it still isn't working. It involves using Run iexplore & IEGet, followed by navigate, but I keep getting the error "Error: Call to nonexistent function".on IEGet. I've tried putting in the Title Bar of my companies homepage, as well as the url for it, but neither works. I also tried just putting in my own webpage that I actually wanted it to launch (instead of the homepage), but nothing works. I don't really know much about the IEGet function, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you did not include the IEget function in your script

Comment: what the other site had (which I also used) was:  Run (pathname)\iexplore.exe   sleep, 250    Pwb := IEGet("(website)")   sleep, 250   pwb.navigate2("(website)",2048)   sleep, 250   pwb.navigate3("(website)", 2048)   etc etc  in the 'IEGet("(website)")' part, I tried using what was in the titlebar (like "website name - Windows Internet Explorer") and also tried using the url, but I get the same error both times.

Comment: Just to clarify what I'm trying to do, I need to launch the .ahk, & have it open a new IE window with 6 tabs in it, then open a 2nd new IE window with 3 tabs in it. After further research, it seems like IEGet may only work on existing tabs, & since my old script (listed in the question) is not launching IE in the way I need it to (with plugins such as Java running), I need to find a new way to launch these 2 IE windows. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit with IE8. From other research it seems like ComObjCreate is launching the wrong -bit version of IE & that's why the plugins don't work.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem & was able to go back to using my original script as noted above. It seems that when running the "ComObjCreate" script, it was opening IE 64-bit, but I only had Java 32-bit installed. so it wasn't recognizing Java in the new IE windows. After I installed Java 64-bit, it appears to be working correctly.